# Objective C - Making UIAlertView wait for user input?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I have a UIAlertView set up with a textfield like so:

```
//***first set of code***  
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"User Input Required" message:@"Please enter data into the field" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];  
    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:nil label:@"[Enter Text]"];  
    [[alert textField] becomeFirstResponder];  
    [alert show];  
    [alert release];  
//***second set of code***`
```

How can I make it so that the user is required to click a button (I have that method already set up to send the input to a string) BEFORE any of the 'second set of code' is fired off?

I need that second set of code to be contained in the same section as the alert (so I can't just run it within the 'dismissWithClickedButtonIndex' method) and that second set of code is using the string obtained from the user input, so that is why I don't want that code to run prior to the user clicking a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. `show` message in UIAlertView won't stop for user input. Associated delegates will need to handle the code you are planning to put in `//***second set of code***` section.

Having said that, let me give you some advice. `addTextFieldWithValue` message is an undocumented API feature. **Do not** use it. It used to be a long time ago that approval process from Apple for you APP would let you pass even if your application used that `addTextFieldWithValue` message. But nowadays that does not happen anymore. Your application will be automatically rejected if it is using that undocumented feature. [Here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/undocumented/alert-with-textfields.html) is a blog entry on the topic.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Don't you just love it when people say "don't do it that way"... and then never give you any good/correct way you SHOULD be doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an old question but you should subclass the UIAlertView and add a textfield. Here is a link: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/alert-view-with-prompt.html